# Ruby Gem Ultraviolet, Rails, Leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, osx-leopard

I cannot get this crazy dependency to work and please don't tell me to go to Snow Leopard because I have a PPC.

I have oniguruma, textpow, ultraviolet all installed. I'm using rvm which is probably the problem. Not that rvm is bad it's just that I don't know how to get the paths correct.

When I startup a rails app the error I'm getting states that I'm missing the `ultraviolet` gem which is not really the case because it's listed under `gem list` with other gems which are working correctly.

Let me know if you need more information and what kinda specific info:

Here is my error log:

> Macintosh:sam samgilman$ script/server
>   => Booting WEBrick
>   => Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
>   no such file to load -- ultraviolet
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in`new_constants_in'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in`load'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in`each'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:164:in`process'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in`run'
>   /Users/samgilman/Sites/sam/config/environment.rb:9
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in`new_constants_in'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`gem_original_require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
>   script/server:3
>   no such file to load -- ultraviolet
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`gem_original_require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in`require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in`require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in`load_gems'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in`load_gems'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:169:in `process'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in`send'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
>   /Users/samgilman/Sites/sam/config/environment.rb:9
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`gem_original_require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in`require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in`require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
>   /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
>   script/server:3
>   Missing these required gems:
>     ultraviolet
>   You're running:
>     ruby 1.8.7.302 at /Users/samgilman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/ruby
>     rubygems 1.3.7 at /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302, /Users/samgilman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@global
>   Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
>   Macintosh:sam samgilman$

Comment: maybe post your `gem env` here
Make sure you're using the version of ruby you think you are.
Also you can try tweaking your gem paths within environment.rb.
GL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I didn't add :lib => 'uv'`

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    config.gem 'ultraviolet', :lib => 'uv'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 3, Rails 4 and Rails 5, you should have `Gemfile`,

```
gem "ultraviolet", :require => "uv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the gem installed is not the same as declaring it in your Rails configuration, though it is an important prerequisite.

Make sure you have your config/environment.rb set with at least:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.gem 'ultraviolet'
end
```

Gems are not automatically loaded until you declare them with the `gem` command. Maybe it's being stubborn, so try this:

```
% irb
> require 'rubygems'
 => true
> gem 'ultraviolet'
 => true
> $:.grep(/ultraviolet/)
 => [...]
```

The final line should show that the load path for libraries `$:` has been adjusted to use your rvm managed gem. It might be missing or incorrect which would prevent the gem from loading properly.

It's often easy to run the wrong `ruby` or `irb` if you're using RVM and your environment isn't consistent. `gem` can often get bound to the wrong ruby if you're not careful about your path.